# Querying related collection by object in pymodm?

Tags: mongodb, python-3.x, orm, pymongo, pymodm

I'm using `pymodm` for ORM in my project.

I have the following simple case:

```
class IdentityRecord(MongoModel):
    alias = fields.CharField()  # normal name for identity


class IdentityImage(MongoModel):
    filename = fields.CharField()  # filename on filesystem
    source_identity = fields.ReferenceField(IdentityRecord)  # reference to an identity
```

As we can see, each `IdentityImage` refers to `IdentityRecord`.

If I have object `IdentityRecord`, then how do I find all records from `IdentityImage` that refer to this object inside python code?

Of course, I can do the following:

```
IdentityImage.objects.raw({'source_identity': identity.pk})
```

However, necessity to user `'source_identity'` string literal kinda defeats the purpose of ORM. Is there any way in this framework to query `IdentityImage` collection by somehow using an instance of  `IdentityRecord` object?

Comment: Hi, did you find a solution for this.

Comment: Hi. I haven’t found the solution for this particular question. Sorry :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Selective queries in a `pymodm.manager.Manager` (such as `IdentityImage.objects` in the example from the question) seem to require a `dict` as the argument for the `get` and `raw` methods. In contrast, the `filter_by` method in a [sqlalchemy query](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/tutorial.html#querying) accepts keyword arguments.

If you prefer keyword arguments to string literals, the following expression seems to work.

```
IdentityImage.objects.raw(dict(source_identity=identity.pk))
```

Omitting the `dict` wrapper in that expression reveals that the `raw` method does not accept field names as keyword arguments. If pymodm were modified to allow that, the notation for such a query would be simpler.

The following code is a mutation of the original code from the question. The first `import` line is implicit in the original code, and explicit here. The other two `import` lines enable the definition and the use of a new class, `KWQuerySet`. Aside from a helper function for the new class, `args`, the only other change is the last line, a new attribute in one of the classes from the original code, which uses the new class.

```
from pymodm import MongoModel, fields
from pymodm.queryset import QuerySet
from pymodm.manager import Manager

def args(arg=None, **kwargs):
    return {**arg, **kwargs} if arg else kwargs

class KWQuerySet(QuerySet):
    def raw(self, raw_query=None, **kwargs):
        return super().raw(args(raw_query, **kwargs))
    def get(self, raw_query=None, **kwargs):
        return super().get(args(raw_query, **kwargs))

class IdentityRecord(MongoModel):
        alias = fields.CharField()  # normal name for identity                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          

class IdentityImage(MongoModel):
    filename = fields.CharField()  # filename on filesystem                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
    source_identity = fields.ReferenceField(IdentityRecord)  # reference to an identity                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
    objects = Manager.from_queryset(KWQuerySet)()
```

With the definition of `IdentityImage` from the mutated code, the following query appears to work correctly in python 3.5.3, with the same meaning for `identity` (an instance of `IdentityRecord`) implied in the example query from the question.

```
IdentityImage.objects.raw(source_identity=identity.pk)
```

It's likely that versions of python prior to 3.5 would require an alternate implementation of the `args` function in the mutated code. I have not fully explored the implications of this change to the notation for queries, but I believe any query which passes `raw_query` as a `dict` should still work, with or without the notation which uses keyword arguments, or a combination of both notations, a dict for `raw_query` and separate keyword arguments for other field names.

Comment: This is already good enough, I will accept this answer - very nice simple idea. However, in my opinion, it still doesn't fully address the problem. But, dict constructor with kwargs is much better. Thanks!

Comment: Fully addressing the problem might be best accomplished by enhancing `pymodm` to handle field names as kwargs natively, possibly with a subclass within the application rather than within `pymodm` itself.